# How to paste clipboard text in a input field with a click on it in jquery

Tags: jquery, clipboard, paste

Do you know a way to paste the text in clipboard (if any) in a input field when the user make click over it with jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following method, but not all the web browsers support it.

See the code and snippet below:

**Note** : You also have to allow your web browser to have access to your clipboard. This is for security reason.

```js
    $('body').on('click', '#test', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        navigator.clipboard.readText()
        .then(text => {
            document.getElementById("test").value = text;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('Failed to read clipboard contents: ', err);
        });

    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="test">
  </form>
```

Comment: instead of `document.getElementById("test").value = text;` you can simply write `this.value = text;`